# How to define and use a custom force using d3-force?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I want to define and use a custom force like centering, radial forces, for which I already have a vector field.

This is the force function I want to use:

```
function force(alpha) {
    viewNode= nodes[0];
    //console.log("hey!!!");
  var thetaArray= [];

  for (var i = 1, n = nodes.length, node; i < n; ++i) {


    node = nodes[i];
    var theta=Math.atan(node.y/node.x);
    if(node.x<0)
    {
        theta+=Math.PI;
    }
    thetaArray.push({theta:theta,index:i});


  }

    thetaArray.sort(function(a,b){return a.theta-b.theta});


  for (var i = 1, n = nodes.length, node1, node2, k = alpha * 1; i < n; ++i) {

    node1 = nodes[(thetaArray[i].index)%n];
    node2 = nodes[(thetaArray[i].index+1)%n];  
    node1.vx -= (node1.y) * k;
    node1.vy += (node1.x) * k;
    node2.vx += (node2.y) * k;
    node2.vy -= (node2.x) * k;

  }
    }
```

Comment: this code will crash. Have you ever looked at `Math.atan2`

Comment: You have defined a function, so what is your actual question? Are you seeing errors?

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for your help. I didn't know about that function.

Comment: @altocumulus I don't know how to use it in a simulation, and not sure if this is the correct way to define it

Comment: You need to make sure you have access to the `nodes` in your function's scope. This can best be done by implementing [force.initialize()](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#force_initialize) which will get passed the array of nodes upon initialization. Have a look at a simple implementation, e.g. forceX, to see how to use a closure to save the reference to the nodes. More details are covered by the article [*Forcing Functions: Inside D3.v4 forces and layout transitions*](https://hi.stamen.com/forcing-functions-inside-d3-v4-forces-and-layout-transitions-f3e89ee02d12).